# How to query products in Akeneo API using an OR conditional

Tags: symfony, doctrine, akeneo

We are tryng to query products using the same value and verifying if that value exists in, at leaste, one of a set of attributes. All the exambples about addFilter() function, are interpreted as an AND condition.

Is there a way to search products in Akeneo using "OR" conditional?

For example: Given a value `myValue`, we want to serach products where `identifier=myValue OR internal_reference=myValue`. (myValue has the same value in both cases)

Comment: Please, take a look at [this FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to check "how to write a good question"

Comment: Indeed currently if you filter your product with many filters, it's an AND condition who is applied

Comment: I need to do the opposite, @Pierre, I need to do an OR condition, but I can't realize how to do it.

Comment: You can't (at least not without specific development).
One possible solution is to make two different call

Comment: Thanks @Pierre. But, then I would have to merge results later, iterating both lists. :-/

If I have to modify code, I don't have problem to do it. I'm looking for what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been talking with Akeneo User group and is not possible to use the standard search, but there are two possible ways to implement the search with an OR conditional:

1. Do different searches and merge the results
2. Create a package/component/add-on with a new endpoint (route + controller method) where you put the query you want to implement.

I know this is not a super answer but I hope this could be useful for reducing the research time for others in the future  :-)